# Jersey2 Custom Date convertor

Tags: date, jersey-2.0, epoch, iso8601

Has anyone created a CustomConvertor class for Jersey2 to convert 
ISO 8601 dates to Date /Epoch time?

I pass date as query param in  ISO_8601_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"; I need to convert to epoch seconds. I have all that is necessary, I am lost in gluing it up.
I want the custom convertor to kick in once we see the DateEpochMarker interface. I use jersey 2

what is step which I am missing?

Could some one please help me out?

I have a customer Convertor, a marker Interface and resource method.

```
public class DateToEpochConvertor implements ParamConverter<Long> {
    private static final String ISO_8601_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
    @Override
    public Long fromString(String value) {
        DateFormat df1 =  new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_8601_FORMAT);

        Date date = new Date();
        try {
            date = df1.parse(value);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("The Date "+value+" is not in the ISO 8601 Format ");
        }

        return date.getTime();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(Long value) {
        DateFormat df1 =  new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_8601_FORMAT);
        Date dt  = new Date();
        dt.setTime(value);
        return df1.format(dt);
    }
}
```

Marker Interface

```
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
    public @interface  DateEpochMarker {}
```

Resource Method

```
     @GET
     @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
     @Path("/epochtime")
     public Long getEpochTime(@DateEpochMarker @QueryParam("startTime") Long          startEpochTime){
    return startEpochTime;
}
```

Comment: FIY, https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2572

Answer (score 2):

I feel foolish to answer my own Question.
Somehow I was not been able to make the above working, what I ended up was using custom Jodatime Convertor.
Pasting the code so that anyone stumbling upon the same query might have a answer

```
@Provider
public class DateTimeParamConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(DateTimeParamConverterProvider.class);

    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations) {
        if (type.equals(DateTime.class)) {
            return (ParamConverter<T>) new DateTimeParamConverter();
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    private static class DateTimeParamConverter implements ParamConverter<DateTime> {
        @Override
        public DateTime fromString(String value) {
            LOGGER.debug("The ISO Date that is provided is   {}", value);
            try {
                return ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis().parseDateTime(value);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                return ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().parseDateTime(value);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(DateTime value) {
            return value.toString();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: [Answering your own question is perfectly fine and actually encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer); just make sure to accept it later (though you [currently cannot](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/), due to the 48-hour wait period).